# Should I do periodic checks in an OnIdle handler or a timer?

Tags: delphi

I want to log the user out of my application after a period of inactivity.

Would it be better to put my check for inactivity in the applciation's OnIdle handler or in a timer handler?

Granularity is not too important. Logout can be plus/minus a few seconds, maybe even a minute.

I get the feeling that the app's OnIdle is going to be firing too often. Any advice? The code iteself is only a few lines.

Comment: Experiment: I created an app with just a memo and a TApplicationEvents in it.
OnIdle, I send a text (timestamp) to the memo.
If you put the cursor in the memo, the application will trigger the OnIdle at a much higher speed.
If you click away from your app (so your app looses focus), it will trigger the OnIdle 3-4 times and then, it will stop until you re-focus your app OR until you move your mouse over the app (even if the app hasn't got the focus).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using GetLastInputInfo to measure idle time. That seems very sensible. So the question boils down to

> Should I do periodic checks in an OnIdle handler or a timer?

OnIdle fires every time the message queue is emptied. If no messages are placed in the queue, OnIdle will never fire. So, OnIdle is not periodic. If you want something to check inactivity regularly, then OnIdle may not work. A timer is certain to work.

You can think of it like this: the OnIdle event fires when the idle counter *starts*, but you need an event to fire when the idle counter *expires*.

> I get the feeling that the app's OnIdle is going to be firing
>   too often.

In fact your problem is the opposite of this!

---

Note that you may experiment with this and find that OnIdle appears to work adequately, and fire regularly. For example, if your app uses any timers then OnIdle will fire following each timer event. Because the timer event comes in on the queue and once it is processed, OnIdle is fired. But if your app has no timers then you can expect OnIdle not to fire at all if you stop interacting with your program.

Comment: TApplication.OnIdle documentation hints about handler's parameter, which you can use to decide if that would be one-time event or a continuous one. In latter case you'd probably wish to thottle it down to avoid 100% CPU core hogging.

Comment: @Arioch That's not pertinent here. If the event doesn't fire at all, it doesn't really matter what happens with its parameters.

Comment: How can it be ? u say that OnIdle is fired on empty queue. That means if it did not fired - the events are in constant flow. I don't think the applicario would never get WM_ACTIVATE or WM_PAINT or WM_MOUSEDOWN - so i don't believe in VCL app with queue empty from second zero to the end

Comment: @Arioch'The If there are no queued messages then `OnIdle` will never fire. Once the message queue contains messages then they will be processed. When the message loop has processed them all, `OnIdle` fires. `WM_ACTIVATE` is not a queued message. It is delivered synchronously.

Comment: Well, okay, i have yet to see any practical VCL application which would never ever have PeekMessage(..)=true. For now i consider this impossible scenario. And at least TS implies that user had some period of activity before getting AFK, so in his application user probably at least once moved mouse, clicked it or striked keyboard.

Comment: @Arioch I have no idea what you are talking about. If you walk away from your computer, `OnIdle` will stop firing. It fires at the end of a burst of message queue pumping. Where does `PeekMessage` come into any of this? Please be clear what you are saying.

Comment: your words "If the event doesn't fire at all" - that means no even single time. If it fires at least once then Done parameter comes to play. You told that there would not be that "one" that Onidle would never ever happen during lifetime of application, not a single time. I want you to specify practical conditions when user would be working with app some time, but Onidle would be fired no any single time at all.

Comment: @Arioch - With *"OnIdle will never fire*", the answer means that it may not fire for an extended period of time after it has fired before. At the last paragraph David explains - *".. if you stop interacting with your program"*

Comment: +1 Thanks very much. I didn't think of that. As it happens, I have other timers and am receiving TCP data over Indy, so I guess that it woudl be ok to use OnIdle. I suppose that if it were a simple standalone desktop app with no timing, then I would have to have a new timer for my check. Thanks for explaining it so well.

Comment: @Sertac that is only if you left default value from Done. This very subtopic started that using OnIdle params you force TApplication to continue calling OnIdle even in absence of windows messages. So in this subtopic discussed the certain case when if it fired once - it would keep firing until user activity resumes.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I use the following.

GetLastInputInfo is from Windows and gives a result telling how long time there has been no keyboard or mouse activity..

TimerLogoffTimer is a timer set to trigger every 5 sec

TimeoutValue is a value that I read from a config

DoLogoff is the procedure that does the actual work of closing forms and so on.

```
function SecondsIdle: DWord;
var
  liInfo: TLastInputInfo;
begin
  liInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TLastInputInfo) ;
  GetLastInputInfo(liInfo) ;
  Result := (GetTickCount - liInfo.dwTime) DIV 1000;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.TimerLogoffTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SecondsIdle >= DWord(TimeoutValue) then
    DoLogoff;
end;
```

Comment: +1 Yup, that's the same code I use to get idle time. Any reason you prefer a timer to the application's OnIdle hendler?

Comment: Not any special reason - this has always worked for me so I have had no reason to change it :-)

Comment: There is indeed a reason to use a timer rather than OnIdle. As per my answer.

Comment: A question about the functionality of this code:  In a test, I put the result of the secondsidle function to the taskbar entry through the Timer event and then minimized the form and did other things.  I noticed it read 0 most of the time except when I wasn't doing anything in any other window.  So is the GetLastInputInfo function global to the system or local to the app?  If it's local, then would this be the solution since the window was likely receiving messages for it to stay at 0 while I'm working elsewhere?

Comment: @Glenn - It's not local to your application, it retrieves the last input time in the session that the application calls the api.

Answer (score 3):

The issue of OnIdle vs TTimer was discussed on the Embarcadero Forums a few days ago:

[Event Handling Question](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=77655)

In particular, [my reply](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=77655#498456) in that discussion explains how the `TApplication.OnIdle` event actually works, and what setting `Done` parameter actually means:

> > I understand that OnIdle is only called once, when the application
> >     begins to Idle.
>
> It is called every time the application enters a new idle state. Every time 
>   the main message loop goes to retreive a message from the main message queue 
>   and no message is present yet, the OnIdle event is triggered and the main 
>   thread enters a sleep state until a new message arrives in the queue. Once 
>   the message is processed an the queue becomes empty again, the OnIdle event 
>   is triggered again and the main thread sleeps until a new message arrives, 
>   and so on.
>
> > If I use this, my checking procedure will only be called one time, and then
> >     the system will continue to wait for user input without checking again.
>
> In the OnIdle event handler, you can set the Done parameter to False to prevent 
>   the main thread from entering its sleep state when there are no messages 
>   to process. That would allow the OnIdle event to keep being triggered while 
>   there are no new messages in the queue. However, that would have the side 
>   effect of disabling TAction.OnUpdate events, though.
>
> > What I want to do is to update a display of a timer.
>
> Then you should be using a real timer ad updating the UI each time the timer 
>   elapses.
>
> > It needs to redraw itself continually, as the time left changes. Maybe there is
> >     another easy way to do this that would be simpler/better.
>
> Look at the TTimer component and its OnTimer event.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have Windows do this for you?

There are policies that will automatically start the screensaver and force logon when the users want to start working again.

As of Windows 7 you cannot work around them with tools like caffeine or other keyboard simulators.

That makes it a lot tighter than anything you can do from within your Delphi app.

Comment: +1 and my apologies, I should have said "I want to log the user *out of my application*"

Answer (score 1):

TTimer uses Windows internal resources which maybe not big deal in today world of gigahertzes and gigabytes but still not nice.

I'd try to use OnIdle or perhaps MainForm.Action for it - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBasicAction.OnUpdate

Both this approaches perhaps would need to throttle down a bit - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ActionUpdateDelay

Note those lines about TApplication.OnIdle though - that is probably
self-chaining event to post stup no-op message to application after
each loop:

> It is not called continuously unless the Done parameter is
>   set to false. Applications that set Done to false consume an
>   inordinate amount of CPU time, which affects overall system
>   performance.

Comment: I don't understand this. Timers are bad because they consume resources. So your solution is to set Done to False!

Comment: 1) are u sure if Done=true spawns timer or posts message ?
At least with explicit use of TTimer you always use it, with Application.OnIdle you may hope on better implementation after Delphi upgrade or switch to FMX or LCL

Comment: 2) even with timer that provides for single shared timer to cover all the forms and their possible Idle handlers, which is practical though irrelevant to the letter of the question

Comment: And there's more. You don't like the resources consumed by a timer and so suggest the use of `ActionUpdateDelay`. See if you can guess what Win32 object is created to implement `ActionUpdateDelay`.

Comment: i am not. Though i know that RTL/VCL sometimes is awfully implemented still some other places are implemented quite well. I did not investigated this particular place

Comment: This part of the VCL is implemented perfectly well. If you ask to keep on receiving `OnIdle` events by setting `Done` to `False`, then the VCL does exactly as you request.

Comment: they probably could use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` instead. But i wonder if it's internal implementation uses implicit timer or not

Comment: Or one can check `PeekMessage` in the handler, if empty - then `Sleep`(0) or `Sleep(50)` and `Done := false;`

Comment: Can't see how that would improve things. You don't like timers but do like Sleep. You've got it back to front.

Comment: Sleep uses task scheduler that works anyway. Timer API is optional system resource that u may use or ignore. Just like threads, in Windows there are lot of threads but does it mean you have to spawn even more without reasons. True, we're not in Win16/Win9x times now, but why allocate resource if can do without it ? Why bother keep and release it when u don't have to ? Well, Sleep(0) still might result in 1005 CPU hoging and Sleep(50) in poor responsibility if program has non-user events like network/database activity. MWFMOEx is better approach probably.

Answer (score 1):

Experiment:

I created an app with just a memo and a TApplicationEvents in it.
OnIdle, I send a text (timestamp) to the memo.
If you put the cursor in the memo, the application will trigger the OnIdle at a much higher speed.
If you click away from your app (so your app looses focus), it will trigger the OnIdle 3-4 times and then, it will stop until you re-focus your app OR until you move your mouse over the app (even if the app hasn't got the focus).

```
procedure TForm3.AppEventsIdle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  Memo.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(now));
  Done:= True;
end;
```

So, this is nothing more than an experimental confirmation of what the above people (David & co.) said: OnIdle is not the best way to continually and reliably do background processing.

__

If you set Done = False, the event is called always, BUT this will hog your CPU. It took a full core in my case, and it barely sent like 30 lines to the Memo. However, the application is (of course) responsive.

--

I think OnIdle is suitable only if you want to quickly process some input that the user entered by mouse or keyboard (for example the user types a string ans you show the TTH of that string in real time. or the user enters a number and you compute if it is prime or not as the user types).

You could even set the Done to False until you finish your (quick) processing, then you switch Done back to True.